# print in python on windows has broken tabulator

Tags: python, windows

What is the reason for this strange print output under windows 7 ?

[Image of strange tab behavior on Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL9KT.png)

Under Linux (Debian Stretch) it looks normal

[Image of normal tab behavior on Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9ymT.png)

Any tip how to fix this? Or what I have to search for?

Comment: Who knows? It's *Windows.* :D

Comment: You could try using spaces instead of tabs. Those are consistent across consoles, platforms, and settings.